# Current password required to change password for self-registered users. No password was ever set

Tags: 7, rules, authentication-authorization, users

I cannot figure out how to validate users through email using drupal.

at `admin/config/people/accounts` I have **Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account** checked, and under *Who can register account* I have it set to **Visitors**.

When I go to create a new account, it says a success message and no email is sent. No errors, nothing in the logs. If I request a password, it sends that email no problem. I can also change my password without entering a current password when using the request password link. So the site is sending emails, just not validation/registration emails.

I have to use rules in order to send the registration emails because the emails are not sending and we have a deadline. I got rules to successfully send the emails but the one time validation link does not exist in the email.

I had to then download [Login One Time](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_one_time) in order to show a validation link in the email.

After clicking the email and successfully logging in as that newly created user, I am unable to change my password because the form is asking for a current password, which is not available for the user to even populate at the registration step.

I have tried using logintoboggan and tried generating temp passwords to send to the user but the token provided by login-toboggan shows up as nothing when the email is sent.

I am seriously confused as to why this is such a difficult process to achieve. Is email validation this difficult out of the box with drupal?

Does anyone know why drupal is prompting me for the **current password** for newly created users?

**Is there something I am missing as to why only registration/validation emails won't fire from my website, but other system emails do?**

Comment: There has to be some code which is stopping registration mails from being sent. Have you removed any submit handlers for registration page? any change done in hook mail alters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue by re-installing the [login one time](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_one_time) module and clicking the **Ignore the current password field** checkbox.

This hides the Current password field for the one time login link, and everytime after requires the user to provide a Current password if they want to change their email, password ect.

The problem is that this website will still ask for a current password for validation links if I uninstall the Login-one-time module, which makes no sense to me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue, and it sounds like it's the one [described here on d.o.](https://www.drupal.org/node/889772)

For me, using [Simple Password Reset](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_pass_reset) ended up being the solution (and with it, its "brief" login form bypass method).